# eslint cannot resolve $ReadOnlyArray

Tags: react-native, eslint, flowtype

When I try to use $ReadOnlyArray, eslint shows error that "$ReadOnlyArray is not defined (no-undef)". I might have a wrong configuration but I don't know where to start.

Here are some env info:

- react-native: 0.51.0
- flow: 0.57
- eslint: 4.9.0,
- eslint-plugin-flow: 6.23.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install Flow type linting rules as follows:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-flowtype --save-dev
```

and your .eslintrc file should look something like this:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
    },
    "plugins": [            
        "flowtype"        
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ;)